# How to clone a SQL Server database using a SQL query

Tags: sql-server

Similar to what exists in Postgres:

```
CREATE DATABASE clonedDB WITH TEMPLATE OriginalDB
```

I am looking for same in SQL Server.
For cloning database on the same sql server.

Comment: Maybe [dbcc clonedatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-clonedatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). I suggest searching the internet to find similar discussions.

Comment: dbcc sometimes have permission issues

Comment: And is not cloning a database is a task that requires elevated permissions as well as an advanced level of tsql skill?

Comment: Task > Generate Script

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has a "template database" that all new databases are a copy of, Model.

> The model database is used as the template for all databases created
> on an instance of SQL Server.

[Model Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database?view=sql-server-ver15)

If you want to copy some other database, use backup/restore or the [SSMS Copy Database Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I need to do this by a query, which I can simply execute using pyodbc, doing through wizard is not under my project scope.

For eg above query for postgres, I simple ran through psycopg2 and it cloned a database

Comment: This answer obligates SSMS which is not part of the OP.

Comment: You can use backup/restore with a query.